# Number Format For Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to set the datagridview values in number format. Currently I am getting this:

[image]

I want something like this:

[image]

I have used this code:

```
dgvmain.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#.##0";
```

And this code

```
dgvmain.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#.##0";
```

But neither of this working.

Comment: How did you add columns, post that code

Comment: Agree without the binding code its hard to spot the error. Alternatively you could already Format your data in the query if a DB is used.

Comment: If you set format after binding a data to `datagridview` then it is not going to work

Comment: It's recommended to autogenerate columns so the DataGridView knows the DataType and can apply a CustomFormat, other wise you can use a StandarFormat.

Answer (score 11):

You can Set you Format String using CellStyle Builder an set the Custom format to # mm

How to do it :

1. Right click on Grid, then Properties
2. In the property window, click the button that will popup up the Edit Columns Dialog
3. Select the cell you want to format
4. On the right side of the Edit Columns Dialog select the DefaultCellStyle property Click the DefaultCellStyle property, then the CellStyleBuilder dialog will open Here you have
   the format property, this will give you the Format String Dialog
5. Set the Custom property to N2 you will see the preview at the bottom
6. Click OK ... till you are back to your Grid...

If you want to do it from Code, put this code inside Form_load event.

```
dgvmain.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

Comment: No no, ofcourse it works. But If that column is not changing regularly, it is better to do in designer. The designer will put this data in .designer file, which separates the existing logic with the design. If you ask me, formatting is a design change not a logic.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question, OP says it is not working, moreover your answer is a suggestion regarding design not related to this question

Comment: I think you don't understand the question. Take a look at OP's first image which clearly shows that no formatting applied. Which even denotes that there is something wrong somewhere else. take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18299794/2530848)

Answer (score 2):

Goto your Form's Design mode then goto the properties of dgvmain there check DefaultCellStyle and set the format as you like.

OR

you can do this

> dgvmain.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";

:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to spot, that all the data on your first screenshot are left aligned.

The formatting you try, and the others adviced are good. I must note, DefaultCellStyle most be used **before** you add columns to the grid.
The case, that it seems specified formats does not work, tells me **your data type may be string, not numeric**.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dgvmain.Columns["Amount"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change "." to ",".

something like this:

```
dgvmain.Columns["your amount column"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,0";
```