# Leading zero in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to display a number with a leading zero in a DataGridView but i don't know how.

for example:

> 3910323 → 03910323

I've tried to add a leading zero to an int/string in a DataGridView and for some reason the DataGridView emits the zero.

How can i format the cells in a way that a leading zero will be displayed?

This is my code:

```
string number = dgvCustomers[0, 0].Value.ToString();
number = "0" + number;
dgvCustomers[0, 0].Value = number;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
dgv.Columns["myColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "D9";
```

BEFORE adding data into it.

More info here:
[Number Format For Datagridview in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299040/number-format-for-datagridview-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank You, but i don't know how to use it , how can i use it to insert a leading zero if the number has less than 9 digit ?

Comment: Try using the format "D9" (instead of the "XXXX" in my code), I never used it myself i'm just guessing.

Comment: Worked like a charm , Thank You

Comment: Side note: you can use "DX" where X is how many numbers you want displayed.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help

```
string number = (string)DataGridView1[iCol, iRow].Value;
number = number.PadLeft(8, '0');
DataGridView1[iCol, iRow].Value = number;
```

Comment: Doesn't work , your solution made an exception in my program (System.InvalidCastException)