# Copying from one Datagridview to another Leading Zero disappear

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

Basically i have 2 dgv, dgv1 is the list(PLU, Desc) and dgv2 is empty with the ff columns (PLU,Desc,Qty). also both dgv is connected to access 2007 table

in the textbox you enter the PLU then the 1st dgv display it. then if you press it will add it to the 2nd datadrigview with a qty=1,

the problem is when every it copies the PLU from dgv1 the leading zero disappear in dgv2.

Search in 1st dgv(on text change)

```
  connect()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE PLU_SKU = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'", connection)
    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    connection.Close()
    da.Dispose()
```

then (on keypress) it save to 2nd dgv

```
connect()
    Dim cmd
    Dim q As Integer
    q = 1

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

        For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            MessageBox.Show(rw.Cells(0).Value)
            DataGridView2.Columns("PLU_SKU").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "D9"

            cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into NEW (PLU_SKU,Description,QTY) values (" & rw.Cells(0).Value & ",'" & rw.Cells(1).Value & "','" & q & "') ", connection)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next

        connection.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Saved")

    End If
    showData1()
```

as you can see i have a messagebox that show me the value of "rw.Cells(0).Value"
and the value is correct. but still i instead of 022 it becomes 22.
now im at a loss on where the problem.

I tried to apply what was said in [Leading zero in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906479/leading-zero-in-datagridview)
but problem is still there.

any help? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, Found my problem seems i forgot the ' in the " & rw.Cells(0).Value & ".
it was supposed to be '" " & rw.Cells(0).Value & "'. thanks anyways.